# Jmeter cannot record properly

Tags: jmeter

The current requirement is to log in from portal A, and then open a new tab to jump to website B to load the page. However, when using the jmeter proxy recording, it is not possible to log in from website A and engage in any interaction. The website implementation is using PHP.

How to solve it？How to solve it？

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't know anything about "portal A" or "website B", it records [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) invoked by your web browser and converts them into [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers.

1. You need to import JMeter's certificate into your browser, see **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) user manual entry for more information
2. In some cases when the system under test is using external authentication subsystems like NTLM or Kerberos you will also need to add a properly configured [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)

Alternatively you can use [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates but you will still need to perform [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters in order to be able to replay the recorded script.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your use case is a bit of a niche case and not typically the type of test that JMeter excels at out-of-the-box.  What it seems like you are describing is emulating client behavior with a dependency on the user experience.

One of JMeter's strengths however, is its extensibility.  There are several ways of accomplishing your use case from the perspective of a JMeter test plan.  Some of these methods have been described above, but one that makes particular sense is using [*Selenium WebDriver*](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/).

The Selenium framework uses actual web browsers (Chrome, FireFox) running in either "headless" mode (without the GUI) and full browser mode (as it would run on an ordinary client machine).  In your described use case, I believe you could accomplish your test using the full browser mode.

Using the [Selenium WebDriver plugin for JMeter](https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-webdriver), it is possible to run your Selenium tests inside JMeter.  However, we need to be cognizant of the performance implications and choose wisely when we want to use JMeter as the framework for hosting a full browser test.  The [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) for JMeter consumes significant resources in addition to the actual browser instance(s), which if unaccounted for can adversely impact the test.  You can read more about these considerations [here](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2022/12/selenium-load-testing/).